# Dynamic Context Menu on Treeview Nodes

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, contextmenu, right-click

Duplicate Of : [Find node clicked under context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/c-treeview-context-menus)

I've got a context menu on a Treeview, when the user right clicks it supposed to change based on the currently right clicked node's tag object.

Currently I'm updating the context menu in after_select event, however this doesn't work when user right clicks to another node without selecting it.

How can I detect which node right clicked and change the context menu? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Too bad you didn't find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/c-treeview-context-menus

Comment: well spotted. Either I'm terrible at search queries of SO search sucks. Anyway updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the MouseDown event and the HitTest method to find out which node was clicked.

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Sub tvTables_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles tvTables.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim M As New ContextMenuStrip
        Dim HTI As TreeViewHitTestInfo = tvTables.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        If HTI.Node.Level = 0 Then
            M = T1Menu
        ElseIf HTI.Node.Level = 1 Then
            M = T2Menu
        ElseIf HTI.Node.Level = 2 Then
            M = T3Menu
        End If
        tvTables.ContextMenuStrip = M
        tvTables.ContextMenuStrip.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```