# Select TreeView Node on right click before displaying ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I would like to select a WPF TreeView Node on right click, right before the ContextMenu displayed.

For WinForms I could use code like this [Find node clicked under context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/c-treeview-context-menus), what are the WPF alternatives?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Depending on the way the tree was populated, [the sender and the e.Source values may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593194/why-e-source-depends-on-treeview-populating-method).

One of the possible solutions is to use e.OriginalSource and find TreeViewItem using the VisualTreeHelper:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

    if (treeViewItem != null)
    {
        treeViewItem.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

static TreeViewItem VisualUpwardSearch(DependencyObject source)
{
    while (source != null && !(source is TreeViewItem))
        source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

    return source as TreeViewItem;
}
```

Comment: is this event for the TreeView or TreeViewItem?

Comment: an Any idea how to unselect everything if the right click is on an empty location?

Comment: The only one answer which helped out of 5 others... I am really doing something wrong with treeview population, thanks.

Comment: In answer to Louis Rhys's question: `if (treeViewItem == null) treeView.SelectedIndex = -1` or `treeView.SelectedItem = null`. I believe either should work.

Comment: This event handler is for the TreeView.

Answer (score 27):

If you want a XAML-only solution you can use Blend Interactivity.

Assume the `TreeView` is data bound to a hierarchical collection of view-models having a `Boolean` property `IsSelected` and a `String` property `Name` as well as a collection of child items named `Children`.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsSelected" Value="true" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

There are two interesting parts:

1. The `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property is bound to the `IsSelected` property on the view-model. Setting the `IsSelected` property on the view-model to true will select the corresponding node in the tree.
2. When `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` fires on the visual part of the node (in this sample a `TextBlock`) the `IsSelected` property on the view-model is set to true. Going back to 1. you can see that the corresponding node that was clicked on in the tree becomes the selected node.

One way to get Blend Interactivity in your project is to use the NuGet package [Unofficial.Blend.Interactivity](http://nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Blend.Interactivity).

Comment: Great answer, thank you!  It would be helpful to show what the `i` and `ei` namespace mappings resolve to though and which assemblies they can be found in.  I assume: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` and `xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"` , which are found in the System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assemblies respectively.

Comment: This didn't help as the `ChangePropertyAction` is trying to set an `IsSelected` property of the bound data object, which is not part of the UI, so it does not have `IsSelected` property. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AntonínProcházka: My answer requires that your "data object" (or view model) has an `IsSelected` property as stated in the second paragraph of my answer: _Assume the `TreeView` is data bound to a hierarchical collection of view-models having a **Boolean property `IsSelected`**..._ (my emphasis).

Answer (score 17):

Using `item.Focus();` doesn't seems to work 100%, using `item.IsSelected = true;` does.

Comment: Good tip. I call Focus() first, and then set IsSelected = true.

Answer (score 14):

Using the original idea from alex2k8, correctly handling non-visuals from Wieser Software Ltd, the XAML from Stefan, the IsSelected from Erlend, and my contribution of truly making the static method Generic:

XAML:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"> 
        <!-- We have to select the item which is right-clicked on --> 
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                     Handler="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"/> 
    </Style> 
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

C# code behind:

```
void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = 
              VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

    if(treeViewItem != null)
    {
        treeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

static T VisualUpwardSearch<T>(DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject returnVal = source;

    while(returnVal != null && !(returnVal is T))
    {
        DependencyObject tempReturnVal = null;
        if(returnVal is Visual || returnVal is Visual3D)
        {
            tempReturnVal = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(returnVal);
        }
        if(tempReturnVal == null)
        {
            returnVal = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(returnVal);
        }
        else returnVal = tempReturnVal;
    }

    return returnVal as T;
}
```

Edit: The previous code always worked fine for this scenario, but in another scenario VisualTreeHelper.GetParent returned null when LogicalTreeHelper returned a value, so fixed that.

Comment: To further this, this answer implements this in a DependencyProperty extension:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18032332/84522

Answer (score 13):

In XAML, add a PreviewMouseRightButtonDown handler in XAML:

```
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <!-- We have to select the item which is right-clicked on -->
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then handle the event like this:

```
    private void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;
        if ( item != null )
        {
            item.Focus( );
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not work as expected, I always get the root element as a sender. I have found a similar solution one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/25e113a5-6f52-4c25-974f-d58b9b689f62/ Event handlers added this way works as expected. Any changes to your code to accept it? :-)

Comment: It apparently depends on how you populate the tree view. The code I posted works, because that's the exact code I use in one of my tools.

Comment: Note if you set a debug point here you can see what type your sender is which will of course differ based on how you setup the tree

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution when it works. It worked for me. In fact, you should just cast sender as a TreeViewItem because if it's not, that's a bug.

Comment: For some reason, setting e.Handled = true causes it to select the root. Removing it seems to fix the issue....

Answer (score 7):

[Almost Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592373/select-treeview-node-on-right-click-before-displaying-contextmenu/594662#594662), but you need to watch out for non visuals in the tree, (like a `Run`, for instance).

```
static DependencyObject VisualUpwardSearch<T>(DependencyObject source) 
{
    while (source != null && source.GetType() != typeof(T))
    {
        if (source is Visual || source is Visual3D)
        {
            source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);
        }
        else
        {
            source = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(source);
        }
    }
    return source; 
}
```

Comment: this generic method seems a little bit strange how can I use it when i write 
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
it gives me conversion error

Comment: TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as TreeViewItem;

Answer (score 7):

I think registering a class handler should do the trick.
Just register a routed event handler on the TreeViewItem's PreviewMouseRightButtonDownEvent in your app.xaml.cs code file like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseRightButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDownEvent));

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    private void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDownEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TreeViewItem).IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! And simple too.

Comment: Hello Nathan. It sounds like the code is global and will affect every TreeView. Wouldn't be better to have a solution that is local only ? It could create side effects ?

Comment: This code is indeed global for the whole WPF application. In my case, this was required behavior so it was consistent for all treeviews used within the application.
You can however register this event on a treeview instance itself so it is only applicable for that treeview.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve it using MVVM is bind command for right click to your view model. There you can specify other logic as well as `source.IsSelected = true`. 
This uses only `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/intera‌​ctivity"` from `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

XAML for view:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TreeViewItemRigthClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

View model:

```
    public ICommand TreeViewItemRigthClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_treeViewItemRigthClickCommand == null)
            {
                _treeViewItemRigthClickCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(TreeViewItemRigthClick);
            }
            return _treeViewItemRigthClickCommand;
        }
    }
    private RelayCommand<object> _treeViewItemRigthClickCommand;

    private void TreeViewItemRigthClick(object sourceItem)
    {
        if (sourceItem is Item)
        {
            (sourceItem as Item).IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem with selecting children with a HierarchicalDataTemplate method.  If I selected the child of a node it would somehow select the root parent of that child.  I found out that the MouseRightButtonDown event would get called for every level the child was.  For example if you have a tree something like this:

Item 1
   - Child 1
   - Child 2
      - Subitem1
      - Subitem2

If I selected Subitem2 the event would fire three times and item 1 would be selected.  I solved this with a boolean and an asynchronous call.

```
private bool isFirstTime = false;
    protected void TaskTreeView_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as TreeViewItem;
        if (item != null && isFirstTime == false)
        {
            item.Focus();
            isFirstTime = true;
            ResetRightClickAsync();
        }
    }

    private async void ResetRightClickAsync()
    {
        isFirstTime = await SetFirstTimeToFalse();
    }

    private async Task<bool> SetFirstTimeToFalse()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return false; });
    }
```

It feels a little cludgy but basically I set the boolean to true on the first pass through and have it reset on another thread in a few seconds (3 in this case).  This means that the next passes through where it would try to move up the tree will get skipped leaving you with the correct node selected.  It seems to work so far :-)

Comment: The answer is to set `MouseButtonEventArgs.Handled` to `true`. Since the child is the first one to be called. Settings this property to true will disable other calls to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can select it with the on mouse down event. That will trigger the select before the context menu kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within the MVVM pattern you could do the following:

View:

```
<TreeView x:Name="trvName" ItemsSource="{Binding RootElementListView}" Tag="{Binding ClickedTreeElement, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:YourTreeElementClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subreports}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTreeElementDisplayProperty}" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="TreeView_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void TreeView_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBlock tb && tb.DataContext is YourTreeElementClass te)
    {
        trvName.Tag = te;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private YourTreeElementClass _clickedTreeElement;

public YourTreeElementClass ClickedTreeElement
{
    get => _clickedTreeElement;
    set => SetProperty(ref _clickedTreeElement, value);
}
```

Now you could either react to the ClickedTreeElement property change or you could use a command which internally works with the ClickedTreeElement.

Extended View:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <TreeView x:Name="trvName" ItemsSource="{Binding RootElementListView}" Tag="{Binding ClickedTreeElement, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HandleRightClickCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:YourTreeElementClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subreports}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTreeElementDisplayProperty}" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="TreeView_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```