# WPF TreeView How to make trigger for IsSelected of treeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

The following code is treeview:

```
   <TreeView BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#ffcccccc"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTypeTreeViewTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTypes}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource treeViewItemStyle}"/>
```

And i set the itemTemplate to set the binding of items. Then set the ItemContainerStyle to change IsSelected style:

```
  <Style x:Key="treeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="itemTypeTreeViewTemplate" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Child}">
                <DockPanel Margin="0,5,0,5">
                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        x:Name="btn1" Width="25"
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter }}"
                        Content="U" DockPanel.Dock="Right" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action EditItemType($dataContext)]" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ItemTypeName}" Foreground="#FF2e8bcc" FontSize="10" FontFamily="微软雅黑" />
                </DockPanel>    
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But the isSelected style is not work. Anybody find the key??

Comment: Use a behaviour like this post? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065995/binding-selecteditem-in-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate-applied-wpf-treeview)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a style trigger, you should override the colour key for the highlighted state. Here's the code:

```
<Style x:Key="treeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <!--<Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>--><!--Remove Style.Trigger block-->
    <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                   Color="LightBlue"/>
        </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps. The other keys for this control are:

- `HighlightBrushKey` - Focussed background. (Is focussed when
  selected)
- `HighlightTextBrushKey` - Focussed foreground.
- `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` - Normal background.
- `InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` - Normal foreground.