# How come left-click on the TreeViewItems that are created with DataTemplate does not select them?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, treeviewitem

```
<TreeView Name="MyTreeView" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityType:MyFixedDevice}">
            <TreeViewItem IsHitTestVisible="True" IsEnabled="True">
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}"
                           IsHitTestVisible="True" IsEnabled="True"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.Items>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Data Warehouse">
            <TreeViewItem.Items>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Platforms">
                   <TreeViewItem.Items>
                       <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, Converter={StaticResource COBJSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Fixed}">
                           <TreeViewItem.Header>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                          Path=Parent.Items.Count,
                                          StringFormat=Fixed Devices ({0})}">
                               </TextBlock>
                           </TreeViewItem.Header>
                       </TreeViewItem>
                  </TreeViewItem.Items>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem.Items>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView.Items>
</TreeView>
```

How come left-click on the TreeViewItems that are created with DataTemplate does not select them? How come if I select them in code, I can't select them again or deselect them?

```
TreeViewItem selectedItem = MyTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
if(selectedItem != null) {
    selectedItem.IsSelected = false;
    MyTreeView.Focus();
}
```

I've tried to use the below to unselect `TreeViewItems` in the `TreeView`, but it only deselects the `TreeViewItems` if they are statically set in the XAML, and not if they are created using an `ItemsSource` and `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually going to do something special with the `TreeViewItem` template for your fixed devices (that requires altering the `TreeViewItem` template?

On the face of it, it seems like you could let the `TreeView` take care of its own items, and just use a simple template for your object representation: e.g.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityType:MyFixedDevice}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I may have misunderstood what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that I'd need to create a `TreeViewItem` object to go into the `TreeViewItem.Items` or it wouldn't be treated as such, but this works for me.

Comment: I believe, because `TreeView` inherits from an `ItemsControl`, that it will automatically wrap all it's items in the appropriate container (`TreeViewItem`). I imange putting another `TreeViewItem` in the template meant that it was wrapped twice, and things got a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `ItemSource` the `SelectedItem` corresponds to the `DataContext` type as in your Type `T` of the `ItemSource` collection you set, not the actual `TreeViewItem`.

hence why your cast fails.

Now when you create them in xaml directly without setting the `ItemSource`, `SelectedItem` is just  the `TreeViewitem` itself and the `as` cast works fine.

**Update:**

It has nothing to with your `DataTemplate`

try this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <x:Array x:Key="someArray"
            Type="sys:String">
    <sys:String>Hello</sys:String>
    <sys:String>World</sys:String>
  </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
  <TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView"
            ItemsSource="{DynamicResource someArray}" />
  <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
          Content="Some" />
</StackPanel>
```

and code-behind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  TreeViewItem selectedItem = MyTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
  if (selectedItem != null) {
    selectedItem.IsSelected = false;
    MyTreeView.Focus();
  } else {
    Debug.WriteLine("Not TreeViewitem");
    Debug.WriteLine(MyTreeView.SelectedItem);
  }
}
```

now when app is run click on an item and then click the `Button`

check the output Window and you'll see

```
Not TreeViewitem
Hello
```

`DataTemplate` merely helps visualize a custom Datatype in the View. This is intended behavior when a collection is bound to the `TreeView`

**Solution:**

in your case to get the Actual `TreeViewItem` try:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  TreeViewItem selectedItem =
    MyTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyTreeView.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;
  if (selectedItem == null)
    return;
  selectedItem.IsSelected = false;
  MyTreeView.Focus();
}
```

^^ this supposedly does not work for `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177290/1834662) for more options.

Comment: But I use a `DataTemplate` to create a `TreeViewItem` for Type `T`.

Comment: @Bob. it has nothing to do with your `DataTemplate` check my update to the answer.

Comment: @Bob. for your requirement I've added a solution at the bottom of my answer. Try and see if that works for you.