# Context Menu for XAML Treeviewitem (Distinguished by different attributes)

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, treeviewitem

In XAML, how do you define a context menu for treeviewitems that are distinguished by different attributes?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### XAML

```
<TreeView Name="SolutionTree"  BorderThickness="0" SelectedItemChanged="SolutionTree_SelectedItemChanged"  >
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key ="SolutionContext"  StaysOpen="true">
      <MenuItem Header="Add..." Click="AddFilesToFolder_Click"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="FolderContext"  StaysOpen="true">
      <MenuItem Header="Add..." Click="AddFilesToFolder_Click"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Remove"/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Move"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

### C-sharp

```
private void SolutionTree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem SelectedItem = SolutionTree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
    switch (SelectedItem.Tag.ToString())
    {
        case "Solution":
            SolutionTree.ContextMenu = SolutionTree.Resources["SolutionContext"] as System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu;
            break;
        case "Folder":
            SolutionTree.ContextMenu = SolutionTree.Resources["FolderContext"] as System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it is just easier to do it in code rather than xaml. I'm not a purest and this works well. Thanks Mr T.

Comment: Right clicking does not select the node.

Comment: @Paul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592373/select-treeview-node-on-right-click-before-displaying-contextmenu

Answer (score 16):

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ScaleCollectionPopup">
      <MenuItem Header="New Scale..."/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ScaleItemPopup">
      <MenuItem Header="Remove Scale"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </TreeView.Resources>
  <TreeViewItem Header="Scales" ItemsSource="{Binding Scales}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ScaleCollectionPopup}">
    <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ScaleItemPopup}"/>
      </Style>
    </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 15):

You could define the `ContextMenu`s in several styles and select the style using a `ItemContainerStyleSelector`, based on those attributes.

Or you could directly specify an `ItemContainerStyle` and select the appropriate `ContextMenu` using triggers

Comment: Sounds like a better approach. Need to still learn styles. Thanks.