# Add\Edit\Remove Right Click Context Menu Of WPF TreeView Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I Want to Add or Change the context menu of treeview of wpf in my C# code.how can I do it???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398943/context-menu-for-xaml-treeviewitem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you need that? Perhaps it would be better to do it in an other way without affecting a code behind? I preffer when View and logic is decoupled, basically this is MVVM approach I would suggest to follow.

Anyway you can do it by adding [Initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isinitialized.aspx) event handler and than handing it in code behind:

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ... />
  <TreeView.ContextMenu Initialized="OnTreeViewMenuInitialized">
    <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
  </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void OnTreeViewMenuInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)sender;
     ...
}
```

Comment: I Have a DLL File(Class Library) that Changes A TreeView To Show Some New Items.and I Can't Edit TreeView's Context Menu in XAML

Comment: I get a WPF TreeView in My Class