# WPF mvvm send TreeViewItem`s binded element via command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, contextmenu

Good daytime.

I've got a problem with creating `ContextMenu` of `TreeView`. The problem is very simple. I want to add new items to treeview clicking RMB on treeviewitem and selecting a context menu command.
I know that I need to pass to my command a parameter that contains parent item. BUT. I need that I can RMB click on any treeviewitem, not only selected.
And heres the **question**:
How to pass the binded data of treeviewitem to my command.

Here is class diag
[image]

Here is Xaml (**EDIT**)

```
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Code}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Name="MyContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding DataContext.ToString()}" Command="{Binding DataContext.Item.AddNewItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>                            
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

But it does not even call my command.

```
    private void AddNewItem(object toItem)
    {
        if (toItem == null)
            return;
        ItemViewModel item = toItem as ItemViewModel;
        ItemMaterialModel itemMaterial = new ItemMaterialModel(ItemModel.CreateNewItem());

        ItemMaterialViewModel itemMaterialViewModel = new ItemMaterialViewModel(itemMaterial);
        item.Children.Add(itemMaterialViewModel);
    }
```

Maybe my command in wrong ViewModel?

Regards, Dmitry.

Comment: have you tried binding it to CommandParameter

Comment: @ethicallogics That is actuallly part of the question. 1st I dont know how to bind it to commandparameter. And 2nd I dont know how to pass NOT selected, but just r-clikcked element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to ethicallogics and his info about PlacementProperty, I've modified my Xaml like here:

```
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Code}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
                            <MenuItem 
                                Header="{Binding Item.Code}"
                                Command="{Binding Item.AddNewItemCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Item}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>                            
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in my `StructureManagerViewModel` I made not simple MainItem, but a collection of MainItems used in itemssourse of tree.

Regards, Dmitry.
Hope this experience will help people.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is just a way you can bind

```
        <ContextMenu Name="MyContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddNewItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
            </ContextMenu>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This is good, but it can be used only  for selected item. I need to detect rightclicked item

Comment: for that you can use the PlacementTarget Property of the ContextMenu

Comment: same result
I think there must be some property that indicates is mouse over the node. Bute using MVVM I dont know where to place it but codebehind

Comment: I am  not sure whats wrong but PlacementTarget guna solve your problem if on right click ContextMenu opens

Comment: What this PlacementTarget exactly must do?

Comment: It gives the reference of UIElement on which your ContextMenu opens

Comment: i have updated solution with some dummy code . you can refer it .In this it works.

Comment: Modified my question, take a look

Comment: I can see issue in it and updated the answer try it.PlacementTarget is a Property of ContextMenu.

Comment: Now it passed some parameter, but it is not correct parameter.
If I Bind `{Binding}` to `CommandParameter` what data should pass?
It passes ItemCollection Of treeview now

Comment: What you exactly want in command parameter . You can extract from it.

Comment: I need DataContext if TreeViewItem on which Right Click were invoked. Im new to wpf and mvvm, so great thanks for your responses.

Comment: if you want MainItem.Code then do CommandParameter="{Binding Header}" ,If you want MainItem.Children then do CommandParameter="{Binding ItemsSource}" . And don,t forget to cast them to their appropriate type because from here you will get the of object type.

Comment: I think I understood one thing. I think I placed my command in wrong ViewModel, or just have wrong class structure. Because when I click on MenuItem I get ViewModel of whole UserControl, but i need to get ViewModel only for one TreeViewItem.

Comment: I have updated my post. Can you tell me which class is binded for context menu now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592373/select-treeview-node-on-right-click-before-displaying-contextmenu) to detect the item under the right click (and select it for positive visual feedback).

Follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162784/WPF-ContextMenu-Strikes-Again-DataContext-Not-Upda) for an explanation of what PlacementTarget is doing in the solution provided by @ethicallogics.

Hopefully you can use a combination of the two answers to solve your problem.