# .NET Treeview doesn't send click event on empty control

Tags: c#, .net, events, user-interface, treeview

I'm working with a .NET Treeview control (not WPF, but regular winforms) and am having trouble with the right-click event (or any click event) not firing when the control has no nodes inside of it.  As per the response to [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/c-treeview-context-menus/2546#2546) on Stackoverflow, my event handler code is as follows:

```
    private void tvTest_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Note: this block below is needed so that the menu appears on
        // the correct node when right-clicking.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            tvTest.SelectedNode = tvTest.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
            if (tvTest.SelectedNode != null)
            {
                tvTestContextMenuStrip.Show(tvTest, e.Location);
            }
            else
            {
                tvTestContextMenuStrip.Show(tvTest, tvTest.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem comes in that while this works fine when nodes are present, if the control is empty, I can't right-click the control and choose "add a node" to add to the root.  The handler isn't entered AT ALL, as I set a breakpoint right at the beginning, and it appears the method is never entered.

Does anybody know how to get "something" to happen when the Treeview is empty?

Comment: Are you using a context menu to add nodes? Is this what you expect to pop-up when the tree contains no nodes?

Comment: This works fine if there's a node there, and doesn't if the Treeview contains zero nodes.  So the menu is fine, it's the MouseClick event that isn't working for me.

Comment: The `TreeView` control is made specifically to handle `TreeNode`s. Try placing/showing a "ghost" control over the tree view when it contains no nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was curious about this particlar problem you described so I created a new project then added a Treeview Control to the form.

I then created an event handler for the MouseDown event, and made it show a message, when the right button is pressed.  If you need the code I am happy to provided upon request, based on the fact its about 2 lines and Visual Studio created the event method I don't see the point.

Comment: Thanks man.  Works good enough.  Still a few pieces of weirdness of creation/deletion, but that may be more about how I'm doing it.  You've solved the fundamental issue.

Comment: If you have any additional questions be sure to ask them.  You could get around this problem by adding a default node if there isn't real data to display.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this was explicitly identified above, but the original poster implies that he's using MouseClick from his code:

```
private void tvTest_MouseClick
```

But the answer responds with an answer to use MouseDown:

> I then created an event handler for the MouseDown event...

I was able to reproduce the original problem by using MouseClick. It seems as if MouseClick is only raised if clicking on a node, but the MouseDown is raised regardless of whether you are on a node or not - so you can choose one or the other depending on the behavior you want.