# How do I get the TreeNode that a context menu is called from?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, treenode

I have a TreeView control with a bunch of TreeNodes.  Each nodes ContextMenu has different MenuItems based on its state. So I am currently attaching each TreeNode its own ContextMenu.

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
TreeNode tn = New TreeNode();
tn.ContextMenu = GetContextMenu(state);
tv.Nodes.Add(tn);
```

Then in the click event for the MenuItem I try to get the TreeNode that the ContextMenu belonged to.

```
MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)sender;
ContextMenu tm = mi.GetContextMenu();
var sc = tm.SourceControl;
```

The problem is that `tm.SourceControl == null`.  I noticed that `TreeNode` doesn't derive from `Control`.  Is that why the `SourceControl` property is null?  How can I get the appropriate TreeNode object? Or even the TreeView object?

Comment: Can you look at this StackOverFlow prior post and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/c-sharp-treeview-context-menus

Comment: That helped.  I didn't see that in my search.  Thanks.  What do I do with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question.

When you have a click on the TreeView, you can do this to get the selected Node and  :

```
void tvMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Select the clicked node
        tv.SelectedNode = tv.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if(tv.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            myContextMenuStrip.Show(tv, e.Location)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't using the TreeView click event I was using the MenuItem click event.  But this helped to figure out my solution.  the Treeview is always available and there is only one. So I just access it directly instead of trying to get it from the event handler parameters.