# Right-click treenode does not return correct treenode

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a tree with multiple nodes.  When left-clicking a node, the AfterSelect event returns the correct node in treeNode.SelectedNode.  However, when right-clicking a node, treeNode.SelectedNode always returns the fist node, not the node I clicked.

For example, if I have a tree with 5 nodes, I would expect that right-clicking the 4th node would set treeNode.SelectedNode to that 4th node; however, I always get the 1st Node.

```
   private void tvDrives_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
   {
       // Always returns 1st node in tree when right-clicking a node
       TreeNode tNode = tvDrives.SelectedNode;  
   }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/find-node-clicked-under-context-menu

Comment: Right clicking doesn't usually select a node (hence @HarisHasan link).  You could use the e.Node property instead of the SelectedNode property.

Comment: Implementing the @HarisHasan link works like a charm.  Thanks!